# Нужны ли тире или запятая перед словосочетанием "Oslo Manual"?

Tags: пунктуация

Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является основополагающий документ в этой области "Oslo Manual".

Answer (score 1):

Если даже тире и возможно, то без него написать точно правильно.

Мне кажется, что лучше поменять слова местами: *Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является основополагающий в этой области документ "Oslo Manual".* Но даже так лично я не очень улавливаю смысл.

Answer (score 0):

> Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является основополагающий документ в этой области "Oslo Manual".

Скорее нет. Наверняка сказать не могу, ибо смысл до конца не ясен.

Тире хочется поставить, по мотивам пунктуационного оформления приложения (основополагающий документ - "Oslo Manual"). Но если "Oslo Manual" - это имя собственное, название, а две заглавных о том свидетельствуют,  то оно не обязательно.

Посмотрите, *Примером внедрения новых технологий является лучший в области колхоз "Красный Лапоть"*. Если бы был уверенным, что у Вас та же грамматическая конструкция, то тире однозначно не нужно. Но тогда я бы и фразу по-другому построил.
***Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является основополагающий в этой области документ "Oslo Manual"***. Если я все правильно понял, повторюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

**Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является методологическое издание "Oslo Manual", основополагающий документ в этой области.**

[Руководство Осло - Рекомендации по сбору и анализу данных по инновациям | studmed.ru](http://www.studmed.ru/rukovodstvo-oslo-rekomendacii-po-sboru-i-analizu-dannyh-po-innovaciyam_c3b3065.html)

В этом случае сначала представляется сам документ, а потом говорится о его значении. Кроме того, улучшена грамматика (в предложенном варианте перед именем собственным находится излишне распространенное  приложение, не очень удобное для прочтения).

Если ничего не добавлять:

**Теоретической базой инновационной деятельности является "Oslo Manual", основополагающий документ в этой области.**

Comment: *является методологическое издание*- отсебятина.

Comment: Можно заменить любым другим выражением, которое подойдет автору, но документ должен как-то быть назван. В то же время для окончательных выводов надо видеть текст.